# arduino & android device connection error because of Manifest

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

it is first time ; i try to connect android mobile phone and arduino with bluetooth. i have part of code ;it must be added in Manifest. i dont know where i can add this code...

`<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.BLUETOOTH” />
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN” />`

my manifest code
`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bluetarduino"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="16" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetarduino.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

`
Also, are there any other way to connect arduino and android mobile devices? Thank you...

Comment: you can refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeep thats true. there is a quotation mark problem. You can delete and rewrite it.

Answer (score 4):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.bluetarduino"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<!--Add your permissions here-->
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.BLUETOOTH” /> 
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN” />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bluetarduino.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

after this part of code
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
          android:targetSdkVersion="16" />`

However in this code there are quotation mark("  ") problem
`<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.BLUETOOTH” /> <uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN” />`

after fix it, it could be work.